# How to indicate that an item in a data table is urgent / very important?

Tags: gui-design, tables, data-tables, status, visual-cues

We have a system that receives certain requests / tasks from customers. There are 2 types of tasks: Urgent and Non-Urgent.

What is the best way to display the task list so that it's easy to see which ones are urgent?

If like below, if there's a new task that is not urgent (that comes in after the urgent task), where should we place it? Should the urgent task be always on top? What if there are many urgent tasks?

[image]

Comment: 'What if there are many urgent tasks?' Then you need to redefine what is urgent.

Comment: In the general case, any (non-urgent) _new_ request would go at the bottom of the list, since anything already _on_ the list should be dealt with first (whether they're urgent or not). Whether urgent tasks always get shown at the top of the list or not depends on business issues such as whether an old, otherwise non-urgent task, can take precedence over a new urgent one (which would probably make it urgent).

Answer (score 1):

### If you have the room, try a status (or 'type') column users can sort by.

From the look of the design above, there's some room to add a column for 'Status'. That way tasks can be sorted, with the status column as a default. (Status might not be the best label, but it's a first thought).

You also might want to differentiate with more than just color for the status indicators, so color blind users can perceive the difference. A text label of 'Urgent' or other statuses might also be necessary, but you can test that first.

I can't tell, but is there a reason to show a user a 'complete' status, so they see what they've done?

You could use an icon that fills in with a check to indicate if so. (Although then you deal with history issues, and I don't know all the requirements you're dealing with).

Non-Urgent could just be the same as an incomplete task.

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fw5oZD.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>